# Laravel Permissions without package

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles

I'm following this tutorial https://learn2torials.com/a/laravel-authentication-based-on-roles.

Works fine and very simple to implement, but I'd like hide some routes for admin roles, so I need to implement permissions, like 'can_view', 'can_update' etc. I read something about Gates and Policy but I'm still confused.

Is a simple way for extends this tutorial? I'd like to avoid using package Spatie/Permissions.

thanks in advance!

Comment: That tutorial already explains how to protect routes using middleware.

Comment: Yes sure, explains how to protect only routes by roles, instead I need to give permission like 'view-post, edit-post, delete-post' at specific user with admin role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this easily using Policies.

Just create the a file in the `app\Policies folder`, with your policy definition:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Expedient;

class ExpedientPolicy
{
  /**
    * Editing allowed for the person in charge of an open expedient
    * @param  \App\Models\User       $user
    * @param  \App\Models\Expedient  $expedient
    * @return bool
    */
  public function editExp(User $user, Expedient $expedient) { 
    return (!$expedient->exp_close && ($expedient->responsible == $user->id));
  }
}
```

And register it in `app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php`:

```
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        Expedient::class => ExpedientPolicy::class,
    ];
```

Now you can use this policy with

`@can('editExp', $expedient)`

Comment: @Iluisma If I have for example five 'admin' accounts, how can I applied this policy and set that two accounts can edit posts and two cannot?

Comment: You can filter them inside the Policy. e.g., if you know their ids:  return (!$expedient->exp_close && ($expedient->responsible == $user->id) && (in_array($user->id, [idA, idB));